# remove "\" character in ruby string

Tags: ruby

i think this is silly question, but i cant find any solution for this problem, maybe you guys can help me out. so i have a string like this:

```
str = "my name is \"leo\""
```

and i want to pass the value to other variable, so the new variable will have value like this:

```
"my name is "leo""
```

i already use `gsub` or `chomp` or `delete` to remove the `\` but that just did not work. however when i using `print` the `\` character disappear, but when i using `p`, the character still visible, like this:

```
(byebug) str = "my name is \"leo\""
 "my name is \"leo\""
(byebug) p str
 "my name is \"leo\""
 "my name is \"leo\""
(byebug) print str
 my name is "leo"nil
```

i hope i can find the answer, thank you guys!

Comment: You should provide an example of exactly what you're trying to accomplish, because whatever problem you're running into, it's not backslashes in the string. There aren't any of those.

Answer (score 4):

There are no backslashes in the string. The backslashes in `str = "my name is \"leo\""` are only there to stop the embedded quotation mark from terminating the string early and making the rest of it a syntax error. The Ruby debugger shows you the string using the same syntax you would need to represent that string value in a literal Ruby expression, so it shows you backslashes, but there aren't any in the string.

You can examine it all sorts of different ways to prove this to yourself.

```
str.length #=> 16
```

If the backslashes were part of the string, that would be 18.

```
str.chars
#=> ["m", "y", " ", "n", "a", "m", "e", " ", "i", "s", " ", "\"", "l", "e", "o", "\""]
```

"Ah-HA!" You say. "Backslashes!" Except notice that they aren't their own characters; they're part of the same string as the double quotes. Why would `chars` group two characters together when its whole job is to make each character its own string? It didn't - each of those is just the single character `'"'`. But the Ruby shell (IRB, byebug, whatever you're using) displays strings using the `#inspect` method, which in turn always uses double quotes. So whenever a string has any double quotes inside it, you're gonna get backslashes in front of them.

```
 (byebug) '"'
 "\""
```

There you can see that I didn't even type a backslash – I didn't have to because I used single-quotes instead of double-quotes. But the shell always shows the value using double-quotes, where it needs the backslash.

Do not confuse the *literal representation in source code* of a string with the *actual value of the string*.  If a string contains a newline, that's a single character with numeric value 10, not a backslash followed by an `n`. If a string contains a tab, it's a single character with numeric value 9, not a backslash followed by a `t`. And if a string contains a double-quotation mark, that's a single character with numeric value decimal 34, no backslashes anywhere.

Here's how to get your string from the comments:

```
str="hmac username=\"USERNAME\", algorithm=\"hmac-sha256\", headers=\"date request-line\", signature=\"sd4XNv5L+z2sLvgkWfcMKEe8vRb89wq33K1F6hibcYk=\""
```

Or, you can use `%Q(`...`)` instead of double quotes:

```
str=%Q(hmac username="USERNAME", algorithm="hmac-sha256", headers="date request-line", signature="sd4XNv5L+z2sLvgkWfcMKEe8vRb89wq33K1F6hibcYk=""
```

Either way, you can interpolate values by replacing the literals with `#{`...`}` expressions. And either way, if you look at the string value in byebug, *you'll still see backslashed double-quotes*, because that's just how byebug prints them out.

If you want some real fun recursion, call `inspect` yourself and look at the representation of the string printed out as the representation. Repeat to taste!

```
str
=> "my name is \"leo\""
irb(main):013:0> str.inspect
=> "\"my name is \\\"leo\\\"\""
irb(main):014:0> str.inspect.inspect
=> "\"\\\"my name is \\\\\\\"leo\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
irb(main):015:0> str.inspect.inspect.inspect
=> "\"\\\"\\\\\\\"my name is \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"leo\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but when i pass the value to other variable, the value still include the "\".

Comment: Any time a string contains a quotation mark, no matter where that string came from, looking at that string in `irb` or `byebug` will show you a backslash because it shows you the string the same way you have to type it in. It's being added _by the ruby shell_. It's _not there_ in the string in memory.

Comment: then how i can have value of string like this "hmac username="USERNAME", algorithm="hmac-sha256", headers="date request-line", signature="sd4XNv5L+z2sLvgkWfcMKEe8vRb89wq33K1F6hibcYk=""

Comment: You can have any character you want in a string. If you have that string you just typed (`hmac...`) in a string variable, and you look at it in `byebug`, you will see backslashes in front of those quotation marks.

Comment: single quote cant do interpolation, that why i need put double quote inside double quote without backslashes

Comment: I don't understand. Are you generating Ruby code? Do you have a string in some other language that contains quotation marks and you're trying to spit out Ruby to do something with it? If that's not the case, just _put backslashes in front of all the double-quotes_.

Comment: @AhmadLeoYudanto write `puts "my name is \"leo\""` in a file,  e.g. file.rb and then run it, ruby file.rb => there is no slash in the output. This answer is correct.

Comment: i get your explanation sir, \ character is always visible when using byebug thats true, but my API header only accept string with double quote inside double quote with no \. that why i struggling to make it posible.

Comment: Unless your "API Header" is reading Ruby source code, I don't see where the problem is. Also, if there's an API that expects double-quoted strings with embedded quotes which aren't quoted somehow (doubled, backslashed, whatever), that's a broken API.

Comment: funny is, my API Header written by javascript in postman, they using grave accent `, and somehow they can remove \ from the string, im sorry i did not tell you at the first place

Comment: You still don't get it. We should take this into a discussion thread. There are no backslashes anywhere. If your ruby code sends the string over the network in an HTTP request, there will be no backslashes sent. The Javascript will not receive any backslashes. THERE ARE NO BACKSLASHES IN THE STRING.

Comment: yeah i think i am, so sorry to bothering you sir, all i want to do is try to re write their postman pre-request script to ruby, to add some header with some value before hit the request. on postman they use variable let says variable = ` hmac username="${hmac_username}" `, they use grave accent which is cant be found on ruby. when i check postman log they will print "hmac username="${hmac_username}"". the grave accent will be replaced by ".

Comment: @AhmadLeoYudanto: **THERE IS NO BACKSLASH IN THE STRING**. The backslash is *shown* to you to make clear that the quote is part of the string, not the end of the string, but **THERE IS NO BACKSLASH IN THE STRING**. You can pass the string to any method you want without worrying about backslashes because **THERE IS NO BACKSLASH IN THE STRING**. You can pass the string to postman without worrying about backslashes because **THERE IS NO BACKSLASH IN THE STRING**. You can store the string in a variable without worrying about backslashes because **THERE IS NO BACKSLASH IN THE STRING**.

Answer (score 3):

You have to distinguish between *string literal* and *string value*.

The **string literal** is what you enter to generate a string, including the surrounding quotes:

```
str = "hello, world"
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#     string literal
```

If you inspect the string in IRB, Pry or Byebug, it will be printed back to you in its *literal form*:

```
str
#=> "hello, world"
```

The **string value** on the other hand is the sequence of characters the string actually contains. In the above example that would be the 12 characters between the quotes, i.e.:

`h` `e` `l` `l` `o` `,`   `w` `o` `r` `l` `d`

---

Now, if you want to have a double quote inside a double-quoted string, you have to escape it with a backslash: (as you did)

```
str = "my name is \"leo\""
```

When inspecting the string, Byebug will print it back to you in its literal form:

```
str
#=> "my name is \"leo\""
```

But those quotes were just added for displaying purposes. Despite the output, the string value is:

`m` `y`   `n` `a` `m` `e`   `i` `s`   `"` `l` `e` `o` `"`

So there's nothing wrong with your string. It's just Byebug's output that looks a little strange to you.

You can happily pass the string around the way it is, it doesn't contain any backslashes.

---

If you have to enter strings with both, double quotes and interpolation, Ruby provides yet another string literal: `%Q(...)` – it allows you to enter doubles quotes without escaping:

```
name = "leo"
str = %Q(my name is "#{ name }")
#=> "my name is \"leo\""
```

(of course, Byebug will show backslashes again, but as said before, that's just for displaying purposes)

Comment: thank you for answer dude, yeah it seems strange to me, because i was comparing my code to postman javascript code, somehow postman log did not show the \ character, so i thought the ruby console like byebug will do the same, but when i see \ character on byebug i get confused, so yeah maybe just i am that did not get the idea of ruby string

Comment: @AhmadLeoYudanto that can be really confusing, especially if it's unclear whether a `\"` in a log is a literal backslash or just an escape character. Maybe you can figure it out more easily by using hard-coded strings in the beginning and then adding interpolation later.

Answer (score 1):

You confound the string data with its representation in a language (Ruby in this case).

The value of the `str` variable is `my name is "leo"`. There isn't any `\` in it. You can check this by printing its value:

```
code = "my name is \"leo\""

puts code
```

[See it in action.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pzk/JVXBVkEpt1IhLzE3VSGzWCFGKSc1P0ZJiYuroLSkWAGk4v9/AA)

The `\` character is needed to represent that value as code in Ruby. The quotes (`"`) are a special character that is used by the language to enclose the string data. When the compiler parses the code and reaches the part `code = "` it knows that to the variable `code` will be assigned a value of type `string` (i.e. text data).

Without `\`, when the compiler reaches the fragment `"leo"` it thinks the string ends here. Because you want to have `"` inside your string you have to tell the compiler somehow that the `"` characters that surround the word `leo` do not have their special meaning designated by the language syntax rules but must represent themselves. This is where `\` comes to the rescue. It "escapes" the character that follows it and tells the compiler to not interpret it in any special way but take it as is.

All in all, the notation `\"` is used to represent a `"` inside a string delimited by `"`, `\'` is used to represent a `'` in a string delimited by `'` and `\\` is used to represent a `\` in a string, no matter how it is delimited. There are other escape sequences for special characters in strings, all of them start with `\`, but they are language conventions; the `\` is not present in the data.

The [`p` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) calls [`inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-inspect) and its purpose is to help debugging the code; therefore it displays technical information (like the text data encoded as Ruby code, for example).